# Slider Render Issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, rendering

I have a WPF Application where I need to draw a large slider. The problem is drawing that large slider has a severe performance issue. What I did was reduce the size of the slider and redraw it when is needed. That is when `Scrollviewer` is scrolled and the slider is out of range, I place the slider in the Correct position and set it's min and max value.

It works fine until I want to reach the end near my thumb, it is rendered in a different place and interacts from a different one, given that there is very large area to scroll.

[image]

As you can see in the picture I need to place mouse in the red zone to drag the thumb but the thumb is drawn in a different position.

If anyone of you have a solution to this problem and know the reason, it would be a great help.

Sample Code is given below

Thanks in Advance.

> Move the Scroll to the end and try dragging the thumb to reproduce the
>   problem.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SLiderTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="600000000">
            <Grid x:Name="_grid" Width="10000">
                <Slider x:Name="slider" />
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>

    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
namespace SLiderTestApplication
{
    #region

    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    #endregion


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.slider.Maximum = 10000;
            this.slider.Value = this.slider.Maximum;
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var left = this.scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - this.slider.ActualWidth + 200;

            if (left < 0)
            {
                left = 0;
            }

            this._grid.Margin = new Thickness(left, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what the problem is, it's unclear on what to do exactly to reproduce the problem. Also I hope it does not involve the missing handlers `Slider_OnPreviewMouseUp` and `Slider_OnValueChanged`.

Comment: Move the Scroll to the end and try dragging the thumb to reproduce the problem. And sorry about missing handler, they can be removed

Comment: Read the comment... @KingKing has told you that we cannot reproduce the problem from your provided code and pointed out that your referenced `Slider_OnPreviewMouseUp` and `Slider_OnValueChanged` handlers are missing. If we can't reproduce your problem then we can't help you. Please read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page of the Stack Overflow Help Center for more information on providing a code example that *does* demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @ Sheridan I updated the question above removed the unused references and I repeat run the application and scroll to the end and try changing the thumb value.. Use WPF Inspector to see want i am talking about.

Comment: Could guys recreate the Issue?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the incorrect thumb placement issue. But I am still wondering what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your solution to initial issue doesn't works (maybe it has something to do with that big value for canvas width, reducing value makes problem disappears). And it also looks and feels ugly. Are you sure you want to continue this way? *Larger slider performance issue* - show it, maybe it's possible to overcome or bypass it.

Comment: you've shown us technically what you are doing, but what are you *trying* to do? We don't get why you have a huge scrollbar in a even bigger canvas. what is the slider supposed to do?  why is the canvas so big?  why not make the slider fit the window (not in the canvas) and make its units scale to the larger thing, if that is needed?

Comment: I am creating a Timeline Slider with custom ticks which will prints date and time and have costume look. I will need to represent 5 + month of data in seconds large number of ticks to draw. And if don't split and redraw the ui freezes for a long time. 
@Sinatr This is an Example the real code complected and  long

Comment: Are you trying to make a `graph`? If I was you, then I'd create custom `FrameworkElement` control and simply draw everything in `OnRender` (with clipping, etc). There could be separate `Slider` to give graph position from which to start drawing. Making a huge canvas and hoping it will handle everything is a wrong way of thinking. Depends what kind of `data` you have, it may be enough to data-template (item-template) `ListBox` and it can handle scroll automatically.